# AWS IoT Core (using IoT Rule) to Kinesis Steam/Firehose in Different AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-iot

I wanted to send data from IoT Rule to AWS Kinesis Stream/Firehose. 
Both the IoT Core and Kinesis Steam is in different account.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to have the IoT rule invoke a lambda in the other account. This lambda then publishes to an AWS Kinesis Stream in the same account.

An example of this cross-account rule is given at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/access-cross-account-resources-using-aws-iot-rules-engine/. This states:

> Cross-account access, via AWS IoT Rules Engine, needs resource-based permissions. Hence, only destinations that support resource-based permission can be enabled for the cross-account access via AWS IoT Rules Engine. Following is the list of such destinations:
>
> - Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS)
> - Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)
> - Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3)
> - AWS Lambda

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the IoT Rule -> SNS Topic -> SQS Queue approach as I wanted to Batch the messages.